# biblatex - author name being suppressed

Tags: biblatex

I apologize if this has been asked, but honestly, I do not even know what the correct terminology is.

I am currently getting this behavior (for example):

> [1] F. Lastname1 and F. Lastname2, "Title," Journal, vol. 1, no. 1,
>   pp. 1-3, Jan. 2011.
>
> [2] , "Title2," Journal2, vol. 1, no. 1, pp. 1-3, Jan. 2010.

the references `[1]` and `[2]` have the same author list.  I would like to display the full name in both references (or at least insert a `--`).

I do not even know what this behavior is called, and consequently am having a very hard time finding the correct option to change it.

Here is my source:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[firstinits=true, isbn=false, url=false,  doi=false, style=ieee, defernumbers=true, sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{nameref}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
\begin{document}
\section*{Publications and Patents}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Book Chapters},type=incollection,prefixnumbers={B}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Journals},type=article,prefixnumbers={J}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Peer Reviewed Conferences},type=inproceedings,prefixnumbers={C}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Theses}, type=thesis, prefixnumbers={Th}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Patents},keyword=patent,prefixnumbers={P}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Letters},keyword=letter, prefixnumbers={L}]
\end{document}
```

---

the bib-file looks like this (just a few excerpts)

```
@article{Zelazo2009b,
author = {Zelazo, Daniel and Mesbahi, Mehran},
doi = {10.1109/TAC.2010.2056730},file = {:Users/zelazo/Research/Mendeley Paper Database/Zelazo, Mesbahi/Data strategies \& benchmarks the monthly advisory for health care executives/Zelazo, Mesbahi - 2000 - Decision-analysis software gives hospitals edge in physician performance monitoring.pdf:pdf},
issn = {0018-9286},
journal = {IEEE Transactions on Automatic Control},
month = mar,
number = {3},
pages = {544--555},
title = {{Edge Agreement: Graph-Theoretic Performance Bounds and Passivity Analysis}},
volume = {56},
year = {2011}
}

@article{Zelazo2010,
address = {Baltimore, MD},
author = {Zelazo, Daniel and Mesbahi, Mehran},
doi = {10.1109/TAC.2010.2085312},
file = {:Users/zelazo/Research/Mendeley Paper Database/Zelazo, Mesbahi/IEEE Transactions on Automatic Control/Zelazo, Mesbahi - 2010 - Graph-theoretic Analysis and Synthesis of Relative Sensing Networks.pdf:pdf},
issn = {0018-9286},
journal = {IEEE Transactions on Automatic Control},
month = may,
number = {5},
pages = {971--982},
title = {{Graph-Theoretic Analysis and Synthesis of Relative Sensing Networks}},
volume = {56},
year = {2011}
}

@incollection{Zelazo,
address = {Boston, MA},
author = {Zelazo, Daniel and Mesbahi, Mehran},
booktitle = {Efficient Modeling and Control of Large-Scale Systems},
doi = {10.1007/978-1-4419-5757-3},
editor = {Mohammadpour, Javad and Grigoriadis, Karolos M.},
isbn = {978-1-4419-5756-6},
keywords = {book},
mendeley-tags = {book},
pages = {219--249},
publisher = {Springer US},
title = {{Graph-Theoretic Methods for Networked Dynamic Systems: Heterogeneity and H2 Performance}},
year = {2010}
}

@inproceedings{Zelazo2009d,
address = {Shanghai, China},
author = {Zelazo, Daniel and Mesbahi, Mehran},
booktitle = {Proceedings of the 48h IEEE Conference on Decision and Control (CDC) held jointly with 2009 28th Chinese Control Conference},
doi = {10.1109/CDC.2009.5400513},
isbn = {978-1-4244-3871-6},
month = dec,
pages = {4747--4752},
publisher = {IEEE},
title = {{H2 performance of agreement protocol with noise: An edge based approach}},
year = {2009}
}

@inproceedings{Zelazo2009a,
address = {Seattle, WA},
author = {Zelazo, Daniel and Mesbahi, Mehran},
booktitle = {AIAA Infotech@Aerospace Conference and AIAA Unmanned ... Unlimited Conference},
file = {::},
issn = {1041-1135},
month = apr,
number = {7},
pages = {C3--C3},
title = {{H2 Performance of Relative Sensing Networks: Analysis and Synthesis}},
volume = {21},
year = {2009}
}

@article{Zelazo2011a,
author = {Zelazo, Daniel and Dai, Ran and Mesbahi, Mehran},
journal = {Energy Systems (accepted for publication)},
title = {{An Energy Management System for Off-Grid Power Systems}},
year = {2011}
}
@article{Zelazo2011c,
author = {Zelazo, Daniel and Schuler, Simone and Allg\"{o}wer, Frank},
journal = {Systems \& Control Letters (submitted)},
title = {{Cycles and Performance in Consensus Networks}},
year = {2011}
}

@phdthesis{Zelazo2009c,
author = {Zelazo, Daniel},
school = {University of Washington},
title = {{Graph-theoretic Methods for the Analysis and Synthesis of Networked Dynamic Systems}},
type = {PhD},
year = {2009},
keyword={thesis}
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `mybib.bib` file contents?

Comment: I added some contents from mybib.bib...this should produce the beahvior I described

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you need to define a `bibstyle` that avoids using `dashed` option, as explain in the [section 3.3.2 of the package documentation](http://ftp.kaist.ac.kr/tex-archive/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf). In this case, I included the option `bibstyle=numeric`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[firstinits=true, isbn=false, url=false,  doi=false, style=ieee, defernumbers=true, sorting=ydnt, bibstyle=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{nameref}

\usepackage{filecontents}    
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{Zelazo2009b,
author = {Zelazo, Daniel and Mesbahi, Mehran},
doi = {10.1109/TAC.2010.2056730},file = {:Users/zelazo/Research/Mendeley Paper Database/Zelazo, Mesbahi/Data strategies \& benchmarks the monthly advisory for health care executives/Zelazo, Mesbahi - 2000 - Decision-analysis software gives hospitals edge in physician performance monitoring.pdf:pdf},
issn = {0018-9286},
journal = {IEEE Transactions on Automatic Control},
month = mar,
number = {3},
pages = {544--555},
title = {{Edge Agreement: Graph-Theoretic Performance Bounds and Passivity Analysis}},
volume = {56},
year = {2011}
}

@article{Zelazo2010,
address = {Baltimore, MD},
author = {Zelazo, Daniel and Mesbahi, Mehran},
doi = {10.1109/TAC.2010.2085312},
file = {:Users/zelazo/Research/Mendeley Paper Database/Zelazo, Mesbahi/IEEE Transactions on Automatic Control/Zelazo, Mesbahi - 2010 - Graph-theoretic Analysis and Synthesis of Relative Sensing Networks.pdf:pdf},
issn = {0018-9286},
journal = {IEEE Transactions on Automatic Control},
month = may,
number = {5},
pages = {971--982},
title = {{Graph-Theoretic Analysis and Synthesis of Relative Sensing Networks}},
volume = {56},
year = {2011}
}

@incollection{Zelazo,
address = {Boston, MA},
author = {Zelazo, Daniel and Mesbahi, Mehran},
booktitle = {Efficient Modeling and Control of Large-Scale Systems},
doi = {10.1007/978-1-4419-5757-3},
editor = {Mohammadpour, Javad and Grigoriadis, Karolos M.},
isbn = {978-1-4419-5756-6},
keywords = {book},
mendeley-tags = {book},
pages = {219--249},
publisher = {Springer US},
title = {{Graph-Theoretic Methods for Networked Dynamic Systems: Heterogeneity and H2 Performance}},
year = {2010}
}

@inproceedings{Zelazo2009d,
address = {Shanghai, China},
author = {Zelazo, Daniel and Mesbahi, Mehran},
booktitle = {Proceedings of the 48h IEEE Conference on Decision and Control (CDC) held jointly with 2009 28th Chinese Control Conference},
doi = {10.1109/CDC.2009.5400513},
isbn = {978-1-4244-3871-6},
month = dec,
pages = {4747--4752},
publisher = {IEEE},
title = {{H2 performance of agreement protocol with noise: An edge based approach}},
year = {2009}
}

@inproceedings{Zelazo2009a,
address = {Seattle, WA},
author = {Zelazo, Daniel and Mesbahi, Mehran},
booktitle = {AIAA Infotech@Aerospace Conference and AIAA Unmanned ... Unlimited Conference},
file = {::},
issn = {1041-1135},
month = apr,
number = {7},
pages = {C3--C3},
title = {{H2 Performance of Relative Sensing Networks: Analysis and Synthesis}},
volume = {21},
year = {2009}
}

@article{Zelazo2011a,
author = {Zelazo, Daniel and Dai, Ran and Mesbahi, Mehran},
journal = {Energy Systems (accepted for publication)},
title = {{An Energy Management System for Off-Grid Power Systems}},
year = {2011}
}
@article{Zelazo2011c,
author = {Zelazo, Daniel and Schuler, Simone and Allg\"{o}wer, Frank},
journal = {Systems \& Control Letters (submitted)},
title = {{Cycles and Performance in Consensus Networks}},
year = {2011}
}

@phdthesis{Zelazo2009c,
author = {Zelazo, Daniel},
school = {University of Washington},
title = {{Graph-theoretic Methods for the Analysis and Synthesis of Networked Dynamic Systems}},
type = {PhD},
year = {2009},
keyword={thesis}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}    
\nocite{*}    

\begin{document}    
\section*{Publications and Patents}    

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Book Chapters},type=incollection,prefixnumbers={B}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Journals},type=article,prefixnumbers={J}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Peer Reviewed Conferences},type=inproceedings,prefixnumbers={C}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Theses}, type=thesis, prefixnumbers={Th}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Patents},keyword=patent,prefixnumbers={P}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Letters},keyword=letter, prefixnumbers={L}]

\end{document}
```

[image: fixed entries]

Answer (score 2):

Since version 0.9 several `BibLaTeX` styles have the additional preamble option `dashed=false`.