# Biblatex author name missing (dashed=false and style=authoryear)

Tags: biblatex, sorting

I'm encountering some odd behaviour in biblatex. The author name for multiple-entry citations in the bibliography is being supressed, but the style is defined (=authoryear, as per [answer: define bib style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36795/biblatex-author-name-being-suppressed)) and I have the dashed option turned off (=false, as per [answer: make dashed=false](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49140/get-full-name-twice-in-bibliography)).

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[ pdftex,
        pdfauthor={Michael J Lotinga},
        pdftitle={The Title},
        pdfsubject={The Subject},
        pdfkeywords={Some Keywords},
        pdfproducer={LaTeX with hyperref},
        pdfcreator={pdflatex}
        plainpages = false, 
        pdfpagelabels, 
        pdfpagelayout = OneColumn, % display single page, advancing flips the page - Sasa Tomic
        bookmarks,
        bookmarksopen = true,
        bookmarksnumbered = true,
        breaklinks = true,
        linktocpage,
        colorlinks = true,
        linkcolor = cyan,
        urlcolor  = blue,
        citecolor = magenta,
        anchorcolor = green,
        hyperindex = true,
        hyperfigures]{hyperref} 
\usepackage[sorting=nyt,
            style=authoryear,           
            hyperref=true,
            backref=true,
            maxbibnames=99,
            maxcitenames=1,
            uniquelist=false,
            uniquename = false,
            dashed=false,
            backend=biber]
            {biblatex}

%Redefine citation commands for linking
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{citeyear}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{citeyear}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{ \usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcitetext}[\mkbibfootnotetext]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}
  {\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{textcite}}}
  {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
     {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
     {}%
   \multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}

\makeatother
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  bibliography = {References},% replace "references" with "bibliography"  for `book`/`report`
}


\begin{document}

\textcite{Taylor2004a}
\textcite{Taylor2004b}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Here is my associated .bib file

```
@proceedings{Taylor2004a,
author = {Thornely-Taylor, R.M.},
title = {The prediction of vibration, groundborne and structure-radiated noise from railways using finite difference
methods},
year = {2004},
maintitle = {Proceedings of the 8th International Workshop on Railway Noise},
eventtitle = {IWRN8},
eventdate = {2004-09-08/2004-09-11},
location = {Buxton, UK},
url = {http://www.ruperttaylor.com/RMTT_IWRN8_6.pdf},
}

@inproceedings{Taylor2004b,
author = {Thornely-Taylor, R.M.},
title = {The prediction of vibration, groundborne and structure-radiated noise from railways using finite difference
methods  --  Part 1  --  theory},
maintitle = {Proceedings of the Institute of Acoustics},
year = {2004},
volume = {26},
part = {2},
pages = {69--79},
url = {http://www.ruperttaylor.com/RTT_IOA_SC2004.pdf},
}
```

And here is the bibliography output I am getting:

[image: Example bibliography output]

I'm hoping for an output that lists the author for every single reference, irrespective of whether it is the same as the preceding (or in this case, succeeding) entry! Can anyone make a suggestion as to what might be getting screwed up? I have other references that are behaving similarly, with less similar article titles.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you provide de `.bib` file ?

Comment: The problem probably comes from there.

Comment: Hi Nicolas, thanks for your response; I've added my .bib file to the question. Any thoughts?

Comment: With `biblatex`, `@proceeding`s do not have an `author`, but an `editor`. So either change `Taylor2004a` to an `@inproceeding` or make Mr Thornely-Taylor an editor of the `@proceeding`. See §2.1.1 *Regular Types* of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

Comment: @moewe I have never really understood the difference between the two: `@inproceeding` and `@proceeding`.

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one!

:)

Comment: Well, `@proceedings` is for entire conference volumes, say "Proceedings of the 31st International Foo Syomposium", while `@inproceedings` is for *articles in `@proceedings`*, say "What Is Foo?". As such `proceedings` will generally not have `author`s since they are just a collection of articles by very different authors/the conference attendees.

Answer (score 1):

As I was suggesting in my comment, the compilation issue relies on the `.bib` file. Also, as @moewe identified, the use of the `@proceedings` category does not contain an `author` field. Therefore, it should be replaced either by `@inproceedings` or put the author in the `editor` field.

New compilation with the appropriate `.bib` file syntax:

```
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @inproceedings{Taylor2004a,
    author = {Thornely-Taylor, R.M.},
    title = {The prediction of vibration, groundborne and structure-radiated noise from railways using finite difference methods},
    year = {2004},
    maintitle = {Proceedings of the 8th International Workshop on Railway Noise},
    eventtitle = {IWRN8},
    eventdate = {2004-09-08/2004-09-11},
    location = {Buxton, UK},
    url = {http://www.ruperttaylor.com/RMTT_IWRN8_6.pdf},
    }

    @inproceedings{Taylor2004b,
    author = {Thornely-Taylor, R.M.},
    title = {The prediction of vibration, groundborne and structure-radiated noise from railways using finite difference methods  --  Part 1  --  theory},
    maintitle = {Proceedings of the Institute of Acoustics},
    year = {2004},
    volume = {26},
    part = {2},
    pages = {69--79},
    url = {http://www.ruperttaylor.com/RTT_IOA_SC2004.pdf},
    }

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
```

The main document simply being:

```
\begin{document}
    \textcite{Taylor2004a}
    \textcite{Taylor2004b}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The output obtained:

[image: References output]

Comment: In this case the proper solution is to make both entries `@inproceedings`, not to change the `author` to `editor` - I'd say.